# What library to choose when importing ListFragment class in Android Studio?

Tags: android, import

I'm trying to start writing a ListFragment but when pressing Alt-Enter in Android Studio (in order to import the missing class, ListFragment), I am confronted with a choice between:

a) android.app.ListFragment

and

b) android.support.v4.app.ListFragment

Can anyone tell me why there is a choice and what the difference is between the two?  I have googled many things such as ""android studio" import listfragment choice v4," "app v4 import "android studio" difference," with no luck.  I've also looked at the Android Support Libraries pages, but they only mention the "v4" version and don't confirm the existence of "android.app.ListFragment".

I don't want to choose the wrong thing and melt my CPU, you know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose (b) rather than (a) If you want to make your app use fragments, and want to target devices before API 11. if you're only targeting devices running API 11 or above, you can use (a).

v4 Support Library is designed to be used with Android 1.6 (API level 4) and higher. It allows you to use newer features of Android on older versions of Android.

Comment: But on the webpage (http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html), it says:

Android Support Library, revision 1 (March 2011)

Initial release with the v4 library.

So.... if v4 is the initial release then how is that the newest... and why is there a duplicate with no version specified?

Comment: OK I think I understand.  My min sdk is 16, so I chose a).  Thanks!